# while installing homebrew on mac i'm getting this error Failed during: git init -q

Tags: git, github, terminal, homebrew, macos-mojave

I was trying to install homebrew on my macbook and used the command line command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

given on the website for installing it and I was given this error.

```
Failed during: git init -q
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the exact install command you run?

Comment: I have added the command have a look

Answer (score 0):

Please update your post with the exact command you used. Assuming it's `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`, make sure you've installed Xcode CLT by running `xcode-select --install` in bash. You probably failed there because git was not installed.

Comment: Yes I used the command that command. Now when i try to install xcode clt it shows xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: Have you tried typing `git` in command line to see if it's even there? Your installation of Xcode CLT might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permission error, run the command recomended in the official [troubleshooting page](https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting):

```
cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var opt Cellar Caskroom Frameworks
```

Comment: I downloaded xcode from the app store and then installed home brew.It worked